# Monitor all sorts of ip address in Python or command line

Tags: python, command, line

I am wondering if there is a way to monitor all data flow from the ports of an IP that might not be in my local network. I prefer doing this in Python and/or command line. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm thinking you might want to try nmap, which is for command line. https://nmap.org/

"Nmap uses raw IP packets in novel ways to determine what hosts are available on the network, what services (application name and version) those hosts are offering, what operating systems (and OS versions) they are running, what type of packet filters/firewalls are in use, and dozens of other characteristics. It was designed to rapidly scan large networks, but works fine against single hosts."

Comment: can you give me any examples of how to achieve this?